# How to avoid using System.Reflection for displaying Enum attribute values in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am using an extension method to get the Name of a DisplayAttribute of an enum to load it into a combobox. This seems to be pretty processor intensive and the performance of the UI takes a hit.

What are some different ways to display a friendly name for an enum?

Extension method if you are interested:

```
public static string GetDisplayName<T>(this T enumValue) where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    try
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                        .GetName();
    }
    catch // If there's no DisplayAttribute.Name set, just return the ToString value
    {
        return enumValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have the optimal solution. Reflection is expensive, indeed, but in the case of an enum it isn't a big deal...

Comment: 'performance of the UI takes a hit'  how many times are you calling this and how many enum values you got??

Comment: I mean if you're that worried about performance you could always add caching to this, but IMHO that's probably overkill.

Comment: Well if you are in situation when this really affects perfomance - just cache it, no need to run this code every time - values will not change.

Comment: @Steve, I have a datatable where each row has a combobox that is being filled with a partially filtered list of the enums. The enum itself has about 20 values, so I'm calling it a lot I guess.

Comment: @Chris Don't optimize anything based on a guess, do it based on performance metrics. I doubt that it's a concern. 20 is nothing and DataGrid virtualization will ensure that it only happens for visible rows. If you think 20 enum stringifications for each of 30 or 40 rows is "a lot", your intuitions aren't well calibrated yet. Still, there's no harm in caching them. I'd cache the whole list, myself.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, My feeling of a performance hit came from the debugger. I was previously just using the .ToString method and decided to try to clean it up. Without "stringifying," it had much better performance (at least to my eyes). No doubt my intuitions aren't great for this stuff yet.

Comment: @Chris Hmmm. Well, that's not metrics, but I agree it's not nothing.

Comment: Have you considered that the slow part could be the try block you are entering every time? You can quickly measure things using `StopWatch` instances to narrow down where the time is going within a small function like that. It is always better to measure than to assume when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cache the values, basically.

For example, a `static class EnumDisplayCache<T>` could have a static constructor that populates a `Dictionary<T, string>` using your reflection approach and `Enum.GetValues` etc, with a:

```
public static bool GetDisplay(T value)
    => cache.TryGetValue(value, out name) ? name : value.ToString();
```

then your method becomes simply:

```
return EnumDisplayCache<T>.GetDisplay(enumValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full implementation of a way to setup an enum name lookup only once per enum per application run. Since it uses a static constructor, it will build the lookup map the first time you use if for a given enum type. This implementation keeps the extension method you originally had, but the implementation uses the cached name lookup.

```
// This class caches all value names for an enum the first time it is accessed
internal static class EnumNameCache<T> where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    private static Dictionary<T, string> sNameMap;

    static EnumNameCache()
    {
        sNameMap = new Dictionary<T, string>();
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<T>())
        {
            string valueName = value.ToString();
            sNameMap.Add(value, type.GetMember(valueName)[0].GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name ?? valueName);
        }
    }

    public static string GetName(T value)
    {
        return sNameMap[value];
    }
}

// Contains extension methods for enums
internal static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName<T>(this T value) where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        return EnumNameCache<T>.GetName(value);
    }
}

// Example display attribute with a Name property because System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute cannot be used on enum values
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
internal class DisplayAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public DisplayAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

There will still be some reflection overhead when the name cache is first built for a given enum, but then lookups will be fast after that. Note that a null check is used on the attribute rather than a try/catch block because a null check is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Enum.GetNames(typeof(YourEnum))` which return a `string[]` of all names in your enum.

Comment: but that doesn't achieve the aim of getting the value from the attribute..